# How to use UpdateProgress if control Button is outside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have one TextBox and One Button, When I press this Button gridview is bind according to the Data I have written in TextBox. Its very larger data so it takes time in Searching, binding and displaying of Data in GridView. So I want to use UpdateProgress like lodaing image
But my GridView is in UpdatePanel.

When I press Search Button postback happens, as I am not including TextBox and Button in UpdatePanel. I have tried this but not able to acieve the desired functionality.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID= "UpdatePanel1" ID="UpdateProgressSearch"  runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="ImageSearch" ImageUrl="images/updateProgress.gif" runat="server"/>
        </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: put all the controls in the updatepanel. personally i avoid to use updatepanel. there plenty of ways to put a loader through javascript.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to put all controls in UpdatePanel.
Please suggest those ways

Comment: i think that you can not achieve the desired functionality. i  insist that is easier to use javascript. i faced that problem some years before and i throught away updatepanel.

Comment: For those who are still looking for a solution, you simply have to remove **AssociatedUpdatePanelID= "UpdatePanel1"**. This attribute is usefull if you do a postback, but in your case there is no postback from UpdatePanel1.

Comment: Hi. @vivek jain, just wondering if you managed to do this as need same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If your Button control is not inside update panel, you need to add assync postback tag with the button control. like follows

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="btnFind"  Onclick="btnFind_Click"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <!-- Your Work Goes Here (your grid view control is here)-->
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFind" EventName="OnClick" />      
     </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried the same .
But this is not what I want.
UpdatePregress image is not displaying while loading of GridView after I click the Button

Answer (score 0):

You have to add async post back trigger with search button as control and click as event name into update panel's trigger collection

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="[your search button id]" EventName="Click" />      
</Triggers>
```

Try with simple text instead of image like "Loading.. or updating..", if that will display when update panel is update then problem is in image url, so check it once again and update it.

Edit:

Make sure you have added scriptmanager in you form.

Updated full code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Text="Search" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            your data to update in your case gridview
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            Loading...
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: AsyncPostBackTrigger has only ControlID property not EventName.

Comment: @vivekjain that property is there check out updated full code

Comment: Not Able to see content inside ProgressTemplate :(